# PHP DOMDocument converts & to &amp - how to keep row value

Tags: php, xml, special-characters, domdocument

I am using the PHP DOMDocument and at one moment I am using the createTextNode

```
$copyrightNode = $doc->createTextNode('&#x000A9;');
$copyrightContainer = $dom_output->createElement('copyright-statement');

$copyrightContainer->appendChild($copyrightNode);
```

In the XML that is generated some time later, I am getting:

```
<copyright-statement>&amp;#x000A9;</copyright-statement>
```

And my goal is to have

```
<copyright-statement>&#x000A9;</copyright-statement>
```

Any idea on how to do that?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Check you're not invoking `htmlentities()` or `htmlspecialchars()` anywhere (e.g. in a library or anything)?

Comment: @CD001, I am invoking htmlentities() but on another node, not this one.

Comment: Yeah - just testing it... it seems that DOMDocument will automatically convert all '&' characters to '&amp;'. Using the `createEntityReference()` method will work, but only for certain characters - granted, the copyright symbol is one of those (as `&copy;`) as dave pointed out below... but I don't feel this is a satisfactory way to add in any character. Of course, your XML document should be UTF-8 anyway so you could just write out `©` rather than faffing about with encoding it.

Comment: The other option is to create a CDATA section `$doc->createCDATASection('&#x00A9;')` which will output `<copyright-statement>&#x000A9;</copyright-statement>` to the screen when viewed in a browser ... but will have the CDATA block in the code `<copyright-statement><![CDATA[&#x000A9;]]></copyright-statement>` - depends on what you're working with... interesting problem, not sure if it's possible to resolve in the way you want ... Hmmmmm.

Comment: @CD001, Thank you for your comments. I know for CDATA, but I don't think this is a good solution for me. I read something and apparently, an XML needs to escape the & character with &amp, and dodn't found the solution how to insert it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When PHP outputs an XML document, any characters that cannot be represented in the specified output encoding will be replaced with numeric entities (either decimal or hexadecimal, both are equivalent):

```
<?php

$dom = new DOMDocument;

$node = $dom->createElement('copyright-statement', '©');
$dom->appendChild($node);

$dom->encoding = 'UTF-8';
print $dom->saveXML(); // <copyright-statement>©</copyright-statement>

$dom->encoding = 'ASCII';
print $dom->saveXML(); // <copyright-statement>&#169;</copyright-statement>
```

Comment: Interesting answer Alf, but do you know which encoding to choose in order to get `&#x000A9;` for the © sign ?

Comment: `&#x000A9;` is the same as `&#169;` - one is hexadecimal, one is decimal. It makes no difference which is used.

Comment: Hm, ok, but what if I really need the `&#x000A9;` ? How can I transform the `&#169;` in `&#x000A9;` ?

Comment: `$xml = str_replace('&#169;', '&#x000A9;', $xml);` - according to a [mailing list message](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/xslt/2004-January/msg00062.html), libxml2 only outputs decimal entities. Why do you really need the hexadecimal?

Comment: This will work, but for the copy character only, but what if I have some other characters like this one, where I need the hex value? I need it because I have to create XML's for an organisation that is asking for hex values, no idea why, but it is a requirement.

Comment: You'll have to use something else to post-process the XML file, in that case.

Comment: What do you think about an array of "all" possible numeric -> hex translations and use preg_replace with this array ?

Comment: Good idea! First, find a list of all possible numbers... ;)

Comment: Alternatively, `$xml = preg_replace_callback('/&#(\d+);/', function($m){ return sprintf('&#x%05s;', dechex($m[1])); }, $xml);`

Answer (score 0):

The correct thing to do here is to use the createEntityReference method (e.g. `createEntityReference("copy");`), and then appendChild this entity.

Example:

```
<?php 
$copyrightNode = $doc->createEntityReference("copy"); 
$copyrightContainer = $dom_output->createElement('copyright-statement');
$copyrightContainer->appendChild($copyrightNode);
```

To create `&#x000A9;` you could (I believe) do:

```
$copyrightNode = $doc->createCDATASection("&#x000A9;"); 
$copyrightContainer = $dom_output->createElement('copyright-statement');
$copyrightContainer->appendChild($copyrightNode);
```

Comment: Thank you dave, but this will create `&copy;` and I need to have `&#x000A9;`, it is mandatory.

Comment: Edited, I believe this will work, CDATA sections shouldn't change the amperstand

Comment: Thanks dave, I know for CDATA, but my goal is to really insert the &, not with CDATA.